# 2 Connected Devices - Port Forwarding Issue

Tags: debian, port-forwarding, port, raspberry-pi, dongle

This is a bit confusing for me to explain but I shall try.

I have a raspberry pi, with an apache server running - port forwarding working and it runs fine, I can access from my desktop on http://192.168.0.11/ and externally on external_ip:80

Now, the problem occurs here... I have USB sim dongle (huawei e303) I use to send SMS from, and this works. It even works when I fire up the ip internally on http://192.168.0.11/ from my deskptop. However, the portforwarding does not work as soon as the USB dongle is plugged in.

It isn't using mobile broadband, but the dongle does have it's own ip address of http://192.168.1.1.

So, there seems to be some sort of conflict - how do I bypass this and allow my port forwarding to work again?

Routing table:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ip -4 route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0  metric 202 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1  metric 203 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.11  metric 202 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.100  metric 203
```

Comment: What does your routing table show with and without the dongle plugged in?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying - it looks like this with it connected http://pastebin.com/PcZ5tcD0 and eth1 goes when its unplugged

Comment: @user1472266, your pastebin shows `ifconfig` output.  You can dump your routing table with `ip -4 route`.  It is better to edit your question with updated information than to add it in comments, in images, or with a link to an external site.

Comment: Not sure, if this means anything http://pastebin.com/CrWue7md

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the dongle has a dhcp server on that is handing out a route via the dongle instead of your network.

The quick command line fix for this is to run the command

```
sudo ip route del default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
```

This doesn't fix the problem permanently. A long term fix is to either disable the dhcp server on the dongle or to change the configuration on the host.

An example of how to change the configuration is given in this serverfault post: https://serverfault.com/questions/527383/change-default-route-to-dhcp-interface-without-a-route-push

Answer (score 0):

create one more rule in iptable with option -i eth1. So the rule will be applicable for eth1 interface.

Comment: Hi, sorry for what may sound stupid - but do I just run 'option -i eth1' on ssh?

Comment: show me your ip table rules. Run command    iptables -L

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CEtaHfRg

Comment: I think you added rules in firewall. show me firewall details . Run command firewall-cmd --list-all

Comment: command not found

Comment: where do you add rules in port forwarding ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45043/discussion-between-user1472266-and-gloom700).